# How to edit a text file in an Enter-PSSession session?

Tags: powershell

I use `enter-pssession` to a remote Windows machine and need to edit a file. Is there any editor works in powershell console window?

Comment: This might be a better question for Server Fault

Comment: Yep. [Here's a disappointing answer at Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/186857/how-do-i-edit-text-files-in-the-windows-command-prompt) that says you can use `COPY CON .\filename.txt` to create a new file or paste old contents from the clipboard. It's not user friendly, but that's the state of text-mode editors now.

Comment: I found a [comprehensive breakdown of console mode text editors](https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2018/02/15/wanted-console-text-editor-for-windows/). Some are open source, some are portable, some are feature-heavy.